# What is the difference between ConcurrentBag and ConcurrentStack?

Tags: c#

I've recently found out about the existence of ConcurrentBag collection and tried it out. I wrote this simple script:

```
ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

bag.Add(5);
bag.Add(10);
bag.Add(15);

int result;

if (bag.TryTake(out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

if (bag.TryTake(out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

if (bag.TryTake(out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Output:

```
15
10
5
```

However, the behaviour looks very much like the behaviour of a Stack. Could anyone point out in what scenarios a ConcurrentBag would be more appropriate to use than ConcurrentStack?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A `ConcurrentStack` implies an order of the items (LIFO), but a `ConcurrentBag` does not.

Comment: The behavior is *very* different. A ConcurrentBag isn't a general-purpose container like `ConcurrentStack`. `ConcurrentBag` uses thread-local storage which means accessing data generated by the current thread is a lot faster than accessing data generated by other threads. `ConcurrentBag` is only meant to be used when each thread needs fast access to local data and only occasionally needs to read data produced by other threads

Comment: You can't remove item from `ConcurrentBag` in easy way like from `ConcurrentStack`

Comment: Unless you really need thread-local storage and understand what's involved, don't use `ConcurrentBag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft docs:
"Bags are useful for storing objects when ordering doesn't matter"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=net-5.0

Your simple example indeed looks like a Stack, but if you try for example the following code with another thread:

```
ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

void Test()
{
    AddToBag(1);
    Task.Run(() => AddToBag(2) );
    AddToBag(3);

    while (bag.TryTake(out int result))
        Console.WriteLine(result);
}

void AddToBag(int x)
{
    bag.Add(x);
    Console.WriteLine("Added: " + x);
}
```

The output would be:

```
Added: 1
Added: 3
Added: 2
3
1
2
```

And if you try that with `ConcurrentStack`, you will get 2,3,1 as expected from a stack.

Comment: That's an interesting example, thank you. Does that mean that it first puts the elements that were added from the main thread and then the ones that are added from parallel threads?

Comment: No. Since bags are defined as  "unordered collection of objects", you mustn't make any assumption regarding their order.